# static page send email WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress. I create a static page contact.php. In contact page, I have a contact form, so users would get in touch with me. When the user would click the submit button it should go to index.php and prompting the success of email delivery otherwise display not successful..

**this is the code of contact.php**

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/send-email.php">

    <p class="name">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" size="40" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
    </p>

    <p class="email">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com"   size="40" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    </p>

    <p class="web">
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="000-000-000" size="40" />
        <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
    </p>        

    <p class="text">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Write something to us" cols="40" rows="5" /></textarea>
    </p>

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
    </p>

</form>
```

**send-email.php**

```
<?php
$ToEmail = 'sample@sample.com';
$EmailSubject = 'Contact Form';
$mailheader = "From: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY = " <strong>Name:</strong> " . $_POST["name"] . "";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br> <strong>Email:</strong> " . $_POST["email"] . "";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br> <strong>Telephone:</strong> " . $_POST["telephone"] . "";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br><br> <strong>Message:</strong> " . nl2br($_POST["message"]) . "";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("Failure");


/* echo "<pre>";
  print_r($MESSAGE_BODY);
  echo "<pre>"; */

header("Location: /index");
```

But it's not sending. And the URL looks just like www.site.com/send-email.php

What am I missing in here? Any ideas? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: your action is `action="/send-email.php"`  how do you expect this form to send all data info to `index.php`

Comment: in my send-email.php it has location: /index @wordpresser

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `die("Failure")` might be kicking in and logging the "Failure" message instead of printing it on screen. Or the mail module isn't installed, so it is running into an error where it doesn't know what the `mail()` function even is—admittedly unlikely. Not too sure.

My guess is that your server is not even set up to send mail properly yet. That can be a complicated setup if you are running your own server. If you are on a shared server, it really should be set up already... unless your host is not very good.

*In any case*, if you are running in WordPress I'd recommend installing the [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) plugin by the folks who made WordPress itself. It includes a feature that adds a contact form to a page with a few clicks of your cursor.

If that form won't send an email, there is something wrong that is beyond the scope of the information you provided in your question.

Comment: Hello thanks for ur response, before I imported my site to WP, it was sending email correctly. But when in WP, it doesn't send

Comment: WP cannot overwrite PHP functionality, and all the code I see here is straight PHP and HTML—which makes it very strange that it only stopped working when you went to WP. You might check your log files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="index.php">

    <p class="name">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" size="40" />

    </p>

    <p class="email">
         <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com"   size="40" />

    </p>

    <p class="web">
         <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="000-000-000" size="40" />

    </p>        

    <p class="text">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Write something to us" cols="40" rows="5" /></textarea>
    </p>

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
    </p>

</form>
```

AND YOUR index.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'] == 'Send')) {
    $ToEmail = 'sample@sample.com';
    $EmailSubject = 'Contact Form';
    $mailheader = "From: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = " <strong>Name:</strong> " . $_POST["name"] . "";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br> <strong>Email:</strong> " . $_POST["email"] . "";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br> <strong>Telephone:</strong> " . $_POST["telephone"] . "";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br><br> <strong>Message:</strong> " . nl2br($_POST["message"]) . "";
    $status = mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("Failure");

}

if($status){
    echo "your success message";
}
 ?>
```

try this

ONE MORE THING

Since you are using this on wordpress you should better use [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) funciton of wordpress

Comment: Hi, I have a separate code in index.php so do I really need to put this in it?

Comment: yes you can comment that for sake for testing you can later use it as the way you want